# Can I use "box of chocolates" and "chocolate box" interchangeably?

Tags: prepositions, adjectives, possessives

The same with "list of cities" vs "city list", or "list of users" vs "user list", etc.

Comment: Box of chocolates contains chocolates. A chocolate box may not; it is for them but can be empty. It can also be a box made of chocolate.

Comment: Your examples are not all similar. "Consult the city list," and "Consult the list of cities" are semantically equivalent, but each has a different feel. "Eat the chocolate box" and "Eat the box of chocolates" are referring to different physical things. There is no rule that applies to all these things.

Comment: Note also that 'chocolate box' is also used as an adjective, to describe a certain type of picturesque English village (which often used to appear on chocolate boxes).

Comment: To clarify Daniel's comment: assorted chocolates used to be regarded as a luxury, and were sold in a shallow box with a thick cardboard lid bearing a picture such as flowers, kittens or an idealised country cottage, intended to appeal to women.